# Space between the bars in the UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How do I increase the space between the bars in a UISegmentedControl? Instead of creating a separate button. I want to split the segment control bars.

[image]

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle can yu make it clear

Comment: You'll need to ask a clearer question for me to give you a clear answer. By in between the bars do you mean the size of the middle portion of the segment?

Comment: @iosdev:[segmentController setWidth: forSegmentAtIndex:];

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle i mean the portions between the first segment & second segment and second segment & third segment

Comment: See @ACB's answer below.

Comment: @iosdev, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 7):

Set width using the following method,

```
[segment setWidth: forSegmentAtIndex:];
```

This will allow you to increase the width of the individual segments.

**Update:**
If you want to split the individual segments, you might have to put a custom image as the `dividerImage` to make it look like it is separate. You need to use the below method for setting `dividerImage`.

```
- (void)setDividerImage:(UIImage *)dividerImage forLeftSegmentState:(UIControlState)leftState rightSegmentState:(UIControlState)rightState barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Comment: Check the documentation on how to use these methods, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html